# running a c# test project through an exe file

Tags: c#, testing, powershell, automated-tests, powershell-2.0

I have a bunch of c# tests that I want to run through a powershell script. I am currently doing this by creating a windows application project, writing the tests as a part of a general class and compiling it into .exe and running the exe but its not the right way to go.

How can I, say, create a class (that can come out as .exe) that can run all tests in a given project or some other way that I can easily run all tests through a powershell script, which is used for application deployment

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There are lots of parameters

Example from the link above.

```
mstest /testcontainer:Errors.dll /detail:testtype
```

or (*VS90COMNTOOLS* change to your version)

```
&quot;%VS90COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\MSTest.exe&quot;/testcontainer:Errors.dll /detail:testtype
```

or (change *'Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0'* to your VS folder)

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"  /testcontainer:Errors.dll /resultsfile:out
```

Comment: interesting. This seems to require running from the visual studio command prompt. How can I get mstest to run from powershell?

Comment: is it possible to pass parameters using this method? I couldnt find any. Because, the tests run against a service, which can be configured with multiple parameters and end points. The config is set through an XML file. How can I get the tests to pick up a specific file to use? Is that even possible with MSTest?